# Replace text in multi-line string using text in the same line

Tags: python-3.x

Here's a very dummy example of what I'm trying to accomplish, input is text:

```
{placeholder}, John Jones\n{placeholder}, Ben Franklin\n{placeholder}, George Washington
```

What I want to do is replace every instance of `{placeholder}` with the output of a function using data from the same line, e.g. the first initial and last name (would need to input first and last name to a function).

```
def initializer(name):
    return f"{name.split(' ')[0][0]}. {name.split(' ')[1]}"
```

The desired result would be:

```
J. Jones, John Jones\nB. Franklin, Ben Franklin\nG. Washington, George Washington
```

Comment: is your input `"{placeholder}, John Jones\n{placeholder}, Ben Franklin\n{placeholder}, George Washington"`? or do you have the names in a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression with a replacement function would work:

```
import re

s = "{placeholder}, John Jones\n{placeholder}, Ben Franklin\n{placeholder}, George Washington"

def repl_function(m):
    return "{}. {}, {} {}".format(m.group(1)[0],m.group(2),m.group(1),m.group(2))

print(re.sub("\{placeholder},\s+(.*?)\s(.*)",repl_function,s))
```

prints:

```
J. Jones, John Jones
B. Franklin, Ben Franklin
G. Washington, George Washington
```

*How does it work?*

It captures `{placeholder}` and 2 words (until end of line, not matched by `.*` because `re.DOTALL` is not set and creates 2 groups (2 name parts).

On match, it calls the `repl_function` replacement function with the match object (second parameter of `re.sub` can be a string, a bytes object or a function which accepts one argument: the match object).

Just return the reformatted match object as string by shortening the first name and repeating the other information (this can be done in a `lambda` as well, but it's maybe more readable as a real function)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, wasn't sure how to go about using `re.sub` like this

Answer (score 1):

The following will work assuming you are using Python >= 3.6:

```py
# it is the same function you showed in your question
def initializer(name):
    return f"{name.split(' ')[0][0]}. {name.split(' ')[1]}"

s = '{placeholder}, John Jones\n{placeholder}, Ben Franklin\n{placeholder}, George Washington'
names = [name.rstrip() for name in s.split('{placeholder}, ') if name != '']
output = '\n'.join(f'{initializer(name)}, {name}' for name in names)
```

**Output**

```py
'J. Jones, John Jones\nB. Franklin, Ben Franklin\nG. Washington, George Washington'
```